# PHP json_encode displaying null

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am running an SQL Query in PHP and putting the values into a JS variable:

```
<?php
$return_arr = array();
$sql="SELECT * from customer_billing group by productname ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $return_arr[] =  $result["productname"];
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($return_arr); ?>
    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });             
});
</script>
```

I have 3 rows with the column productname equal to:

- Integra Fibre Unlimited
- Integra Fibre Unlimited (RRP: £59.95)
- Integra Professional Web Hosting

and when i use `echo json_encode($return_arr);`, it displays like:

```
"Integra Fibre Unlimited",null,"Integra Professional Web Hosting"
```

it just doesn't like displaying the second one

Comment: what `var_dump($return_arr);` returns?

Comment: I think you mean `["Integra Fibre Unlimited",null,"Integra Professional Web Hosting"]`.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM customer_billing WHERE productname IS NOT NULL GROUP BY productname;`?

Comment: the productname for the second row is not null anyway

Comment: @SharikovVladislav it shows - "Integra Fibre Unlimited" [91]=> string(37) "Integra Fibre Unlimited (RRP: £59.95)" [92]=> string(32) "Integra Professional Web Hosting"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
// some code
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $return_arr[] =  utf8_encode($result["productname"]);
}
echo utf8_decode(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: Wow. Rly? :D Need explanation?